# Error when using "ORDER BY count" in query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following query to display some information:

```
$result = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * FROM files,members,member_group WHERE files.member_id = members.member_id AND members.member_id = member_group.member_id AND group_id='$id' ORDER BY count DESC ");
```

My issue is it works fine when I leave out `ORDER BY count DESC` but when it is there I get the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /proj/co600/project/repo/public_html/select_field3.php on line 227
```

Count is a column in my database which records the number of times a publication is downloaded.

Comment: Include more code. Your error message refers to mysqli_fetch_array() which doesn't appear here.

Comment: you should use `mysqli_query (..) or die(mysqli_error())` to get the proper error messages do not avoid them

Comment: Do you have a `count` column in more than one of the tables you are querying?

Comment: My guess, without seeing more code, is that you have a `count` column in more than one table and thus the reference in your `order by` clause is ambiguous.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll THAT WAS THE PROBLEM I HAD TWO COUNT COLOUMS ! thank you guys for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count` is an aggregate function, so you need to surround it with backticks.

**To get a clear cut picture of your error.. You need to change your code like..**

```
$result = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * FROM files,members,member_group WHERE files.member_id = members.member_id AND members.member_id = member_group.member_id AND group_id='$id' ORDER BY count DESC ");
if(!$result)
{
 die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: @CodingAnt, I don't understand too :(

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran `count` is not a reserved keyword [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) says clearly **COUNT is acceptable as a column name** and in the keyword list count is not mentioned

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure this is really the problem, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78a39/1 . In fact, count is NOT a reserved keyword (sorry for that, it's a BUILT-IN FUNCTION). And CAN be used as a column name...

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran that edit is meaning full and i guess user should be curious to use columns with their table alias this will overcome the problem of have same column name in multiple tables although +1 for the edit

Answer (score -1):

You are having MySQL reserved keyword as column name in table.

Use Below query:

```
$result = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * FROM files,members,member_group WHERE files.member_id = members.member_id AND members.member_id = member_group.member_id AND group_id='$id' ORDER BY `count` DESC ");
```

Comment: Please [*read docs*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) first before you answer